# JS touch carousel: performance issues

Tags: javascript, ios, performance, web-applications, carousel

I am building a simple web app for iOS using Zepto.js. It’s fairly lightweight, except for one part: its main component, a carousel slider (powered by [swipeslide](https://github.com/max-power/swipeslide)), which can take an indefinite number of items (100+).

With more than a few tens of items, the slide animations on the iPhone become somewhat twitchy and ugly.

Are there any good alternative solutions for creating performant touch-sliding carousels that can support a large number of items on iOS devices?

Comment: I'm sure by now you have solved this, but you may want to look into the TouchSwipe lib from Skinkers Labs: https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin 
For any others looking specifically for a Touch-enabled carousel, I put something together at https://github.com/netpoetica/TouchCarousel - it's powered by jQuery and TouchSwipe and feel free to modify it

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Photoswipe](http://www.photoswipe.com)... It is very effective and powerful.